# System Call on PHP

Tags: php, system-calls

Having a bit of problem with this. 
Script A calls/includes Script B. Script B has to execute a system call and return to Script A. Fails in flames.
When I call Script B on its own, it works just fine, I cannot for the life of me get it to work by calling it on A. Ive already tried

- Including it on A
- Calling it with another system call within A
- Making a bash script that calls B and then calling that bash script with A (I N C E P T I O N)

What are my options here?

Edit for code:

```
<?php
//B.php
//works fine when called on its own
function readsite ($url)
{
      $output=system("curl -ks $url");
      return $output;
}
?>


<?php
//A.php
include_once("B.php");
$url="www.google.com";
$read=readsite($url);
echo $read;
?>
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting? Can you give source examples of how you're calling it and how you're getting results?

Comment: What does your script do? Maybe you have some different paths / environmental variables / etc, but I cannot tell...

Be more verbose.

Comment: B.php may execute on it's own, because all it does is define the function, not actually execute it

Comment: if the script's failing in flames, shouldn't you be trying to find a fire extinguisher instead of posting here?

Comment: My guess from the code is that you need to set `http://` before the URL, but we need to see the error.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a system command instead of curl from php?

Comment: @lonesome: curl's smart enough to assume http if it's not explicitly specified.

Comment: @Mark Baker I meant I can make it work by  hardcoding the variables and not making it a function.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the problem you are trying to solve here is fetching the contents of a website.

Give the following a try:

```
function readsite($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

The curl extension provides you with a relatively sane and stable way to fetch stuff in php. [Look at the docs for more information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php)

This assumes availability of the php-curl extension though.

And of course (as lonesomeday pointed out) you should add the scheme to the url (use 'http://www.google.com' as url).